# Is it posible to get all the values of the text boxes with the same name?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a doubt in javascript. Is it posible to get the values of text boxes with the same name ?

for example

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="">
<INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="">
```

these text boxes have same name, how can i get its values by name ?

OK, lemme come to the real problem i got, hope am explaining correctly.

I have a series of text boxes which i gotta validate now. Its not a big deal to validate textboxe normally.

But this is an array of text boxes where the id of the text boxes will be available only when the fields are added dynamically by clicking on the + button. when the press button is clicked the whole set of text boxes will appear. as many times its clicked, it will get added.

So its imposible to get the values to validate with the ID, so i tried by name.

JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION

```
function insComep()
    {

    // $("#doctorPri").validationEngine("updatePromptsPosition")  
// jQuery("#doctorPri").validationEngine('attach', {promptPosition : "topRight"});

        rl=document.getElementById("compeTable").rows.length;
        var a=document.getElementById("compeTable").insertRow(rl);

        var g=a.insertCell(0);
        var f=a.insertCell(1);  
        var m=a.insertCell(2);  
        var n=a.insertCell(3);  
        var o=a.insertCell(4);  
        var p=a.insertCell(5);
        var q=a.insertCell(6);
        var r=a.insertCell(7);
        var s=a.insertCell(8);
        var t=a.insertCell(9);
        //var v=a.insertCel1l(11);
        //var u=a.insertCell(12);
g.innerHTML='<select name="competproduct[]" style="width:86px" id="competproduct'+rl+'" class="validate[required]" ><option value="">--Select--</option><?echo $product_str;?></select>';
f.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="competcompany[]" id="competcompany'+rl+'" size="10" class="validate[required]" >';
m.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="competbrand[]" id="competbrand'+rl+'" size="10" class="validate[required]" >';
n.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="competdrug[]" id="competdrug'+rl+'" size="10" class="validate[required]" >';
o.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="competquty[]" id="competquty'+rl+'" size="2" class="validate[required,custom[integer]] text-input" >';
p.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="competprice_frm[]" id="competprice_frm'+rl+'" size="2" class="validate[required,custom[number],funcCall[getPriceFromE]] text-input" />';
q.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="competprice_to[]" id="competprice_to'+rl+'" size="2" class="validate[required,custom[number],funcCall[getPriceTo]] text-input" />';
r.innerHTML='<input type="text" name="competmrp[]" id="competmrp'+rl+'" size="2" class="validate[required,custom[number],funcCall[getMrp]] text-input"/>';
s.innerHTML='<select name="ChemistParma[]" style="width:86px" id="ChemistParma'+rl+'" style="width:86px" ><option value="">--Select--</option><?echo $chemist_str;?></select>'; 
t.innerHTML='<img src="media/images/details_close.png" onClick="delCompe('+rl+'); "/>';
// jQuery("#doctorPri").validationEngine('attach', {promptPosition : "topRight"});


     $("#doctorPri").validationEngine('hideAll');
    }
```

HTML

```
<table width="100%" id='compeTable' border='0' style='margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;margin-top:40px;' >


<tr style="border-bottom:1px solid #999999;"><td colspan='4'>
<div style="background:;padding:3px;text-align:left; ">
    <font color='black'><strong  >Competitor Detail(s):</strong></font><font color="red">*</font>
</div>

</td></tr>



        <tr>
        <td>Product Name:<font color="red">*</font></td>
<td>Company Name:<font color="red">*</font></td>
<td>Brand Name:<font color="red">*</font></td>
<td>Drug Name:<font color="red">*</font></td> 
<td> Quantity:<font color="red">*</font></td>
<td>Pricefrom Dist:<font color="red">*</font></td>
<td   >Price to Dist:<font color="red">*</font></td>
<td> MRP:<font color="red">*</font></td>
<td>Chemist<font color="red">*</font><input type='button'value='+' style='width:1px' style='width:1px'  onclick='frame5()'/> 
</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>


            <tr>


                    <td>
                    <select name='competproduct[]' id='competproduct' style="width:86px" class="validate[required]" >
                    <option value=''>-select Product-</option>
                    <? echo $product_str;?>

                    </select>
                </td>

                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="competcompany[]"  id="competcompany" size="10" class="validate[required]" >
                </td>
                <td   ><input type="text" name="competbrand[]" id="competbrand" size="10" class="validate[required]" >
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="competdrug[]" id="competdrug" size="10" class="validate[required]" >
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="competquty[]"  id="competquty" size="2" class="validate[required,custom[integer]] text-input" >
                </td>
                <td>
<input type="text" name="competprice_frm[]" id="competprice_frm" size="2" class="validate[required,custom[number],funcCall[getPriceFromE]] text-input" />

                </td>
                <td>
                <input type="text" name="competprice_to[]" id="competprice_to" size="2" class="validate[required,custom[number],funcCall[getPriceTo]] text-input" />
                </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="competmrp[]" id="competmrp" size="2" class="validate[required,custom[number],funcCall[getMrp]] text-input" onBlur=''/>
                </td>
<td>
<select name='ChemistParma[]' id='ChemistParma'  style="width:86px">
<option value=''>-select chemict-</option>
<?echo $chemist_str?>
</select></td>
<td>
<img src="media/images/details_open.png" onClick="insComep()"/>
</td>

                </tr>
        </table>
```

Comment: This is very simple with jQuery and I can post an example, but first I need to know from you if using jQuery is an option or whether you need pure JavaScript without any additional frameworks. EDIT: Posted a non-framework answer below, but beaten to it :)

Comment: I think your HTML tags aren't closed off properly here either btw, I think you need    <input .... />

Comment: Here i just wanna validate the price to dist shouldnt exeed MRP. how can i do that now

Comment: I know i should write a function, but have no idea as the fields are multiple and dynamicly addable..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple,

```
document.getElementsByName("inputBox");
```

Comment: I dont think it would help , as its useful only with checkboxes and radio buttons. But not with text boxes.

Comment: @Bala.C — An input with a name is an input with a name. It doesn't matter if it is a checkbox or a text input. You get a NodeList and loop over it. The only difference is that you only care if it has a value or not if it is a text input (if it were a checkbox you would also care if it was `.checked`).

Comment: Nope, i tried many times, it will not work with that..! if it worked for u, please correct me..!

Comment: Working example with demo here: http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Development/GetelementbynamegetElementsByName.htm

Answer (score 2):

You can use a multitude of different methods.

1) Manual traversal of childNodes etc, and checking for nodeName. This is pretty involved and requires a lot of boring code, so I won't write an example of that here.

2) `document.getElementsByTagName`. This can also be used on DOM nodes, so you can do something like `document.getElementById("my_form").getElementsByTagName("input")`, depending on how the rest of the DOM looks of course.

3) `document.querySelectorAll("input")`. The string argument is a full CSS selector. Some older browsers doesn't support this though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example for you with your code:

```
<div id="inputs">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="asd">
    <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="inputbox" VALUE="efs">
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {  
        var howmany = $('#inputs').children("input").length;
        alert(howmany);

        for( i=0; i<= howmany-1; i++ ) {
            var input = $("#inputs").children("input").eq(i).attr('VALUE');
            alert(input);
        }
    });
</script>
```